# what's the typeof(jQuery)

Tags: jquery

i just tried this code

```js
console.log(typeof(jQuery))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It alerts `function`, which means the `typeof` jQuery is `function`.

My question is, what's the exact type of jQuery? If it's function, how come it has properties like `jQuery.browser` and `jQuery.ajax`?

Comment: I believe all JavaScript 'object's are functions. Javascripts OO is kind of weird till you get used to it.

Comment: Because objects are functions and functions are objects in Javascript.

Comment: Close, @Matthew, all functions are objects, not the other way around.

Comment: @ray: to use a function  as object we must use 'new' key word, like new User(). But in case of jquery why dont we do that

Comment: @Rusi: you need to work on your title-ing.

Comment: @Rusi, actually no.  You can create a function with the `function` expression, the `function` declaration, _or_ by using `new Function(..)`. In _all three cases_ the function is indeed an object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The typeof operator when applied to the  `jQuery` object returns the string `"function"`.  Basically that does mean that `jQuery` is a function.

But the typing sort of stops there.  Unlike statically typed languages, the number, order, modes, and types of parameters are not taken into account when computing the type of a a function.  In JavaScript, it is just a "function."

When you create a function in JavaScript, the function object you create is given two properties, `length` and `prototype`, and its prototype is set to `Function.prototype` so it has inherited properties like `apply` and `call`.

And as others have already answered, feel free to add your own properties.  a function is just an object.

But be careful about "type."  Techncially there are only **SIX** types in JavaScript: Null, Undefined, Boolean, Number, String, and Object.  So the real answer to your question, what is the exact type of `jQuery` is .... actually ... drumroll .... **Object**.

#### Edit for 2021

There are now EIGHT types in JavaScript. `Symbol` and `BigInt` have been added since this answer was written a decade ago.

Comment: If jQuery is actually an object, which is a subset of function, and object is valid type, then why doesn't `typeof jQuery;` return "object"?

Comment: Because JavaScript doesn't care about type hierarchies. There is no notion of type objects, nor supertypes or subtypes. The `typeof` operator returns a _string_, not a _type_. Types are things defined in the language reference; you don't really deal with them in code much, you just get a string back from the `typeof` operator. [Here is the description of the operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). You can see that it was not intended to make a lot of sense. It just does what it does.

Answer (score 6):

A function is an object and can have properties in Javascript.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function for a look at some of the properties a function has by default (and additional properties can be added).

Answer (score 4):

Just try to do it yourself and you'll understand:

```
function f() {
}

f.prop = '123';

alert(f.prop);
```

`jQuery` is a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) but, of course, it is also object, that contains own functions, like `call()` and can have properties as well.